# Filtering of data based on a DSL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, dsl

Our's is a product specific to a domain.Here are some of the typical security use cases,

1. A normal User can edit only his profile data or anybody data based on permission
2. A user can see only data that belongs to his department while another user can data from all departments

These requirements changes from customer to customer so we can not just hard code the filtering logic in our application code or maintain multiple versions of the application.

We use Hibernate criteria based filtering and like to add additional Restrictions based on some expressions associated with a Permission. An expression for use case 1, mentioned above, may look like this, `'userId=user.userId'` where 'user' is a keyword and represents current authenticated user and 'userId' is a property of the object for which criteria is created.

We want to define a dsl using which we can derive criteria restriction as well as 'where' clause for sql.

Are there any existing frameworks which will enable us to do it, without going for dsl? Based on the use cases mentioned above, do you think it can be achieved in different way?

Additional Info: We define only domain objects with some meta information to generate UI. Persistence, security etc are taken care by our core framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We decided to go with our own dsl using antlr

Answer (score 2):

Have you tested Hibernate filters?
They are great mechanism for record level filtering, you can define multiple filters (for example two filters for your case) on each entity and enable or disable them according to current user.
Shall mention that filters can accept parameters (for example your current user id).

We have used this great feature of Hibernate 3 on a large project, which had a hierarchical organization unit and that worked fine.

By the way if you use Oracle as your database, consider Oracle's virtual private database feature.

Comment: Amir, I am aware of Hibernate filters but it does not fit for our needs. Thanks for the suggestions.